# Is such association possible in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `List` model and a `User` model. A `List` belongs to a `User` and also can be followed by many `Users`. How do I make association so that I can do such operations:

- `list.user` - gives me the user that created(belongs to) the list.
- `list.followers` - gives me a list of users following the list.
- `user.following` - gives me all the lists followed by a user.

can someone please help me create such associations in rails as well as how do I create migrations for this association.

Answer (score 0):

First of all generate a user model.
Then for list model, give migration like:

```
$rails g model list user:references follower_id:integer followee_id:integer
```

then `$rake db:migrate`

Now in `list.rb`

```
validates_uniqueness_of :followee_id, scope::follower_id
```

Hope it helps

**Edit**
so for full code do refer my blog https://additionalknowledge.wordpress.com/2017/08/06/making-follow-mapping-on-rails/#more-559 follow each step don't miss.

Comment: sorry I am new to rails, I didn't quite get it. Do I have to make Follower and Followee modes for this? What about the association between user and list? and how do i achieve the operations I need.. like: list.user, list.followers etc like I have mentioned in my questions..

Comment: User is passed as the reference to the list model. You have to write ruby code and make changes in user.rb , and in your html page where you want to display that list and make changes where you want to give link. A proper code needs to be written for this.

Comment: And yes you have to define follow modes in your user.rb file like make can_follow and can_unfollow and make a followmapping.

Comment: If you have time, could you please elaborate with sample code. That would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: So I have made a blog for you, just follow each step thoroughly,

Comment: ohh!! thanks a lot.. am i missing something or did you provide link to the blog somewhere else??

Comment: yep in answer https://additionalknowledge.wordpress.com/2017/08/06/making-follow-mapping-on-rails/#more-559

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I will follow along your blog and let you know if it works!! Thanks a ton!!